# Kneewall Scuttle vault door won’t close

Tags: doors, attic

I recently moved into my first house and we’re in a bit of a pickle. The bedroom that our baby sleeps in has a metal door on the wall (too high to access w/o a ladder) and try as we might, we can’t get the door to close. Presumably a lot of our heating is pouring into this tiny scuttle attic space… I’m wondering if there is an issue here with a heating leak into the space (from, say, our HVAC) that’s creating positive pressure that’s opening the door every time we try to shut it (with a broom - it won’t stay closed). The house was built in 1965…and this is the first of many questions I have about the home. [image]Thanks in advance for any tips you can offer about how to handle this and how to prevent the door from continuously opening. Happy new year!

Comment: I suspect a ~6 foot  A-frame ladder is worth buying.  Homeowners need a ladder.  If the costs are too much, see if there's a hire company nearby.

Comment: Yes, you'll need a good ladder at some point _anyway_, so you may as well get it now. Don't get the shortest possible (4-foot, for example), because then you're unsafe just standing high-enough to easily operate at an 8-foot ceiling. That is, _not_ "step-stools". :)

Answer (score 7):

I believe the answer is in your picture. The two cutaway areas on the insulation appear to be associated with internal metal "toggles" that are probably turned by a screwdriver on the face of the door we can't quite see.

[image]

If climbing up there is the problem, buy or borrow a stepladder - you'll need one from time to time with a house. Banging with a broom won't fix it. 5 seconds with a screwdriver (or possibly the edge of a coin) will.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. If querent has not noticed the screwdriver slots then they are probably painted over, in which case 5 sec will not do it -- he'll need at least 1 minute of scraping. Also, it's difficult to see with all that metal foil in the picture, but the upper latch seems to be badly bent -- there goes another minute.

Comment: I am really confused by the picture.

Comment: @Z4-tier: Most of us were. Ecnerwal is familiar with this type of door and decoded the photo by *knowing the latches were there*. - Note also Jack's answer, he also knows about these doors.

Comment: Bingo! Yes, we will need a 6-foot stepladder. The interior-facing door had indeed been painted over, obscuring the latch access mechanisms. The bottom latch was just about accessible - yes, from a step stool - and we’ve closed that one so far. I can’t thank you all enough 

Answer (score 4):

Those types of metal doors in all the instances I have seen have a slot within a small circle on the edge of the door for a screwdriver the turn the latch that keeps the door closed.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are not going to fix this without climbing up there at least once. Since you have many house problems requiring your attention, you want a quick simple reliable solution, even if it is unattractive or inelegant.

The best quick fix is a toggle latch. This is nothing more than a short stick pinned to the wall with a screw in the middle, next to the door on the side opposite the hinges. Locate it so that when the stick is vertical, the door just clears it, but when turned horizontal, one end holds the door shut.

The hole through the stick should be drilled out before inserting the screw, and a washer should be inserted under the screw head, so the stick will turn freely.

The proper conventional fix is a latch with a screwdriver slot, and striker plate. You can do this later, when you have the time, after you've taken care of all the other problems with this house... I can't even type this with a straight face. Just use a nice-looking stick.

Comment: Of course you should try @Ecnerwal's solution first. The toggle latch is only if the door hardware is completely kaput.